# Using rename to rename files and directories

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I'm using the Linux rename command line tool to search recursively through a directory to rename any directories as well as files it finds. The issue I'm running into is the rename command will rename a sub-directory of a file then attempt to rename the parent directory of the same file. This will fail because the sub-directory has been renamed resulting in a "No such file or directory"

Command:

```
rename -f 's/foo/bar/' **
rename -f 's/Foo/Bar/' **
```

For example, here is an original file that I would like to replace 'foo' with 'bar'

File:

```
/test/foo/com/test/foo/FooMain.java
```

Failure:

```
Can't rename /test/foo/com/test/foo/FooMain.java /test/bar/com/test/foo/FooMain.java: No such file or directory
```

Preferred File:

```
/test/bar/com/test/bar/BarMain.java
```

You can see from the error message that it's attempting to rename the parent directory but at that point the subdirectory has already been changed resulting in the file not found error. Is there parameters for the rename command that will fix this or do I need to go about this in a different way?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using Unix tools. Unix.stackexchange.com or SuperUser.com would be more appropriate.

Comment: Moved to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366780/using-rename-to-rename-files-and-directories

Answer (score 0):

Use find + execdir option:

```
$ find . -execdir rename "s/foo/bar/" {} \;
$ find . -execdir rename "s/Foo/Bar/" {} \;
```